# Variance of Negative Binomial Distribution (without Moment Generating Series)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, negative-binomial

Given the discrete probability distribution for the negative binomial distribution in the form

$$P(X = r) = \sum_{n\geq r} {n-1\choose r-1} (1-p)^{n-r}p^r$$

It appears there are no derivations on the entire www of the variance formula $V(X) = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$ that do not make use of the moment generating function.

I have successfully managed to compute the mean without this as follows;

\begin{align*}
\mu = \sum_{n\geq r} n{n-1\choose r-1} (1-p)^{n-r}p^r 
&= \sum_{n\geq r} \frac{n(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r}p^r \\
&= \frac{r}{p} \sum_{n\geq r} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r} p^{r+1}\\
\end{align*}
Having already factored our claimed mean of $r/p$, it remains to show that $\sum_{n\geq r} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r} p^{r+1} = 1$ which is done by reindexing (both $r$ and $n$) and realizing this as the sum of a probability mass function for a negative binomial distribution. Indeed, letting $k = r+1$ followed by $m = n+1$, we find

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq r} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r} p^{r+1} &= \sum_{n\geq k-1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}(1-p)^{n-k+1}p^k\\
&=  \sum_{m\geq k}\frac{(m-1)!}{(k-1)!(m-k)!}(1-p)^{m-k}p^k\\
&=  \sum_{m\geq k}{m-1\choose k-1}(1-p)^{m-k}p^k  = 1
\end{align*}

Does anyone know of a way to demonstrate that $\sigma^2 = V(X) = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$ in this fashion?

Comment: Usually when you calculating with some cancellation of factorials, you may consider something similar to the factorial moment: $ Var[X] = E[X(X+1)] - E[X] - E[X]^2$

Comment: Thanks, this made it for me. For some reason I kept trying to evaluate $E[X(X-1)]$  with no success.

Comment: The answer posted below by "The Cryptic Cat" begins by saying a negative binomially distributed random variable is the number of independent trials needed to get $r$ successes, with probability $p$ of success on each trial. But I think it's better to work with the number of failures before the $r$th success, so that the support of the distribution is $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ rather than $\{r,r+1,r+2,\ldots\},$ for two reasons: $(1)$ you still have a well defined distribution when $r$ is not an integer, and the family of all such distributions still has$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the property that if $X$ is negative-binomially distributed with parameters $r_1$ and $p$ and $Y$ with $r_2$ and $p,$ and they are independent, then $X+Y$ is negative-binomially distributed with parameters $r_1+r_2$ and $p,$ and $(2)$ it makes it clearer why the term "negative binomial" is used. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

No need to index twice. The process is quite similar to the way you get $E[x]$

I believe the problem here is how to get $E[x^2]$

Please refer to [Markus Scheuer's efforts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672714/proof-for-the-calculation-of-mean-in-negative-binomial-distribution/1675392#1675392):

In his answer he derived:
$$
\begin{align*}
E(x)&=rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+r}{k}(1-p)^k\\
\end{align*}.
$$
Follow the similar way, and apply to $E[X^2]$
$$
\begin{align*}
E(x^2)&=rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)\binom{k+r}{k}(1-p)^k\\
\end{align*}
$$
We need a way to change $(k+r)$ to $(k+r-1)$, then the outside $(k+r)$ can be combined with $(k+r-1)!$ as $(k+r)!$, so I refer [to the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)
$$
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
(k+r)\binom{k+r}{k}&=(k+r)\binom{k+r-1}{k-1}+(k+r)\binom{k+r-1}{k}\\
&=(r+1)\binom{k+r}{k-1}+r\binom{k+r}{k}\\
\end{align*}
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align*}
E(x^2)&=rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)\binom{k+r}{k}(1-p)^k\\
&=rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[(r+1)\binom{k+r}{k-1}+r\binom{k+r}{k}](1-p)^k\\
&=rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[(r+1)\binom{k+r}{k-1}](1-p)^k+rp^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[r\binom{k+r}{k}](1-p)^k\\
\end{align*}
$$
then, still, use [Markus Scheuer's idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672714/proof-for-the-calculation-of-mean-in-negative-binomial-distribution/1675392#1675392) in 
remember to use 
*[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*

Finally, you will get
$$
\begin{align*}
E(x^2)&=\frac{r(1-r-p)}{p^2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
V(X)&=E(x^2)-[E(x)]^2\\
&=\frac{r(1-r-p)}{p^2}+\frac{r^2}{p^2}\\
&=\frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I do like [The Cryptic Cat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/314621/the-cryptic-cat)'s answer. I was also trying to find a proof which did not make use of moment generating functions but I couldn't find a proof on the internet. So I made an attempt.

Given
$$P(X = n) = \sum_{n\geq r} {n-1\choose r-1} (1-p)^{n-r}p^r,$$
where $n=\text{number of trials}$ and $r=\text{number of successes}$.

You have already to managed prove that
$$E(X) = \mu = \frac{r}{p}$$

Since expectation is a linear operator, rather than computing $E(X^2)$, it will be easier to find

$$\begin{align}
E(X(X+1)) &= E(X^2+X) = E(X^2)+E(X) \\
&= \sum_{n\geq r} n(n+1){n-1\choose r-1} (1-p)^{n-r}p^r \\
&= \sum_{n\geq r} \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r}p^r \\
&= \sum_{n\geq r} \frac{(n+1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}\frac{r(r+1)}{r(r+1)}(1-p)^{n-r}p^r \\
&= \frac{r(r+1)}{p^2} \sum_{n\geq r} \frac{(n+1)!}{(r+1)!(n-r)!}(1-p)^{n-r}p^{r+2} \\
&= \frac{r(r+1)}{p^2} \sum_{n\geq r} {n+1\choose r+1}(1-p)^{n-r}p^{r+2}
\end{align}$$

Since
$\sum_{n\geq r} {n+1\choose r+1}(1-p)^{n-r}p^{r+2} = 1$,
$$E(X^2)+E(X) = \frac{r(r+1)}{p^2}$$

This implies that
$$E(X^2) = E(X^2)+E(X)-E(X) = \frac{r(r+1)}{p^2}-\frac{rp}{p^2} = \frac{r(1+r-p)}{p^2}$$

Therefore,
$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 = \frac{r(1+r-p)}{p^2}-\frac{r^2}{p^2} = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, so I have it here as an answer.

Funny you ask this, since I was trying to figure this out yesterday. To prove that the Negative Binomial PDF does sum over $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ to give $1$, you will need to make use of the binomial theorem for negative exponents (as Alex has indicated) and the fact posted at [Negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619651/negative-binomial-coefficient/) (but note the way this is written is for the "other" negative binomial distribution, with $K = X-r$).

The second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is a bit tedious to compute. You will need to do reindexing twice rather than once with $\mathbb{E}[X]$. Unfortunately, the form of your negative binomial PDF is different from the one I worked with ($K = X-r$, as indicated above), so I don't have a sketch of this.

Answer (score 1):

The negative binomial distribution with parameter $r$ is the distribution of  the number of times, $X$,  a Bernoulli experiment $B$ with probability $p$ has to be repeated independently to have it succeed for the $r$-th time.

Define $X_i$ to be the random variable denoting the number of times $B$ has to to be performed to succeed for the $i$-th time after having succeeded $i-1$ times. $X_i$ is a geometric random variable with probability of success $p$. Therefore the variance of $X_i$ is $\dfrac{1-p}{p^2}$. The $X_i$'s are all independent and hence we have,

$$ \operatorname{Var}[X]=\operatorname{Var} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^r X_i\right]=\sum _{i=1}^r \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = r\cdot\frac{1-p}{p^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\begin{split}
E(X^2)&=\sum \limits_{n=r}^\infty n^2\tbinom{n-1}{r-1}p^rq^{n-r}\\
&=\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty (r+t)^2\tbinom{r+t-1}{r-1}p^rq^{t} \qquad (let \ n-r=t)\\
&=p^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty (r+t)\frac{(r+t)!}{(r-1)!t!}q^{t}\\
&=p^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty r\frac{(r+t)!}{(r-1)!t!}q^{t}+p^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty t\frac{(r+t)!}{(r-1)!t!}q^{t}\\
&=r^2p^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \frac{(r+t)!}{r!t!}q^{t}+rp^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \frac{(r+t)!}{r!t!}tq^{t}\\
&=r^2p^rp^{-r-1} + rp^r\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \tbinom{-r-1}{t}t(-q)^{t}\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+rp^rq\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \tbinom{-r-1}{t}(-t)(-q)^{t-1}\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+rp^rq\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \tbinom{-r-1}{t}\frac{d(-q)^t}{dq}\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+rp^rq\frac{d}{dq}\sum \limits_{t=0}^\infty \tbinom{-r-1}{t}(-q)^t\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+rp^rq\frac{d(1-q)^{-r-1}}{dq}\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+\frac{(r+1)rq}{p^2}\\
Var(X)&=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2\\
&=\frac{r^2}{p}+\frac{(r+1)rq}{p^2}-\frac{r^2}{p^2}\\
&=\frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}
\end{split}
$