# mean and variance formula for negative binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning, negative-binomial

The equation below indicates expected value of negative binomial distribution. I need a derivation for this formula. I have searched a lot but can't find any solution. Thanks for helping :)

$$
E(X)=\sum_{x=r}^\infty x\cdot \binom {x-1}{r-1} \cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{x-r} =\frac{r}{p}
$$

I have tried:
\begin{align}
E(X) & =\sum _{x=r} x\cdot \binom{x-1}{r-1} \cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{x-r} \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{x=r}^\infty x \cdot \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! \cdot ((x-1-(r-1))!} \cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{x-r} \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{x=r}^\infty \frac{x!}{(r-1)!\cdot ((x-r)!} \cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{x-r} \\[8pt]
\Longrightarrow & \phantom{={}} \sum_{x=r}^\infty r\cdot \frac{x!}{r!\cdot (x-r)!}\cdot p^r \cdot (1-p{)}^{x-r} \\[8pt]
& = \frac{r}{p} \cdot \sum_{x=r}^\infty \frac{x!}{r!\cdot (x-r)!}\cdot p^{r+1}\cdot (1-p)^{x-r}
\end{align}

If the power of $p$ in the last equation were not $r + 1,$ I can implement Newton Binomial. So It will be true. But I am stuck here.

Comment: If you *must* use a multiplication symbol, please use `\cdot` instead of `\times`. It makes it hard to read when there are crosses and $x$’s everywhere.

Comment: I have updated my post. Thanks for commenting)

Comment: The expression $\binom{x - 1}{r - 1} p^r (1 - p)^{x - r}$ is the probability of there being $x$ *trials* until the event with probability *p* occurs *r* times. The negative binomial distribution gives the probability of there being $x$ *successes*, not trials, so what you are calculating is something different.

Comment: Negative Binomial Distribution has two forms. Please, look at the links: http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture16.pdf
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovh113q3yragh9p/jb_ies_110_CC.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @joshua or even four forms according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)

Comment: Yes @Henry. It is so complicated distribution, I think. I need the proof of mean and variance of the second form of nb  distribution you shared

Comment: I suspect the easiest way of finding the mean and variance of a negative binomial distribution is as the sum of $n$ iid geometric distributions

Comment: @Henry You are right, I know the derivation by using $ E(X)=E({X}_{1}+{X}_{2}+X3+....+{X}_{n})=r\times \frac{1}{p}=\frac{r}{p}$ . I mean  sum of expectations. But I need the proof by using $E(X)=\sum _{x}^{}x*p(x)$

Comment: I appreciate that you have enlightened me to *four* different definitions of the negative binomial distribution. I didn’t think to use trials vs. successes or $p$ vs. $1 - p$ as options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance of Negative Binomial Distribution (without Moment Generating Series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620945/variance-of-negative-binomial-distribution-without-moment-generating-series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue that derivation instead of using linearity of expectation on a sum of i.i.d. geometric random variables, then you can follow this; however, doing it this way is much more complicated than the method using the i.i.d. variables.

When you arrive at the step $\operatorname{E}(X) = \sum_{x\geq r} r \binom{x}{r} p^r (1 - p)^{x - r}$, we can use this fact about power series:

$$
\frac{1}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}} = \sum_{n\geq r} \binom{n}{r}z^{n-r}, \quad \text{for }\lvert z\rvert < 1.
$$

If this fact is unfamiliar to you, then you can derive it from the geometric series $\frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n\geq 0} z^n$ by differentiating both sides $r$ times and dividing by $r!$. Of course, we are tacitly assuming that $p \neq 0$ in order to use this. Otherwise, the event that we want to occur $r$ times could not occur at all!

It follows that

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}(X) &= r p^r\sum_{x\geq r} \binom{x}{r} (1 - p)^{x - r} \\
&= rp^r \cdot \frac{1}{\big(1 - (1 - p)\big)^{r + 1}} \\
&= rp^r \cdot \frac{1}{ 
p^{r + 1}} \\
&= \frac{r}{p}
\end{align*}$$

We can do something similar for the variance using the formula

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var} X &= \operatorname{E}\big(X^2\big) - \big(\operatorname{E}(X)\big)^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}\big(X(X + 1)\big) - \operatorname{E}(X) - \big(\operatorname{E}(X)\big)^2.
\end{align*}$$

This means that

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var} X &= \sum_{x\geq r} x (x + 1)\binom{x - 1}{r - 1} p^r (1 - p)^{x - r} - \frac{r}{p} - \frac{r^2}{p^2} \\
&= \sum_{x\geq r} r (r + 1)\binom{x + 1}{r + 1} p^r (1 - p)^{x - r} - \frac{r p + r^2}{p^2} \\
&= r(r + 1)p^r \sum_{x\geq r+1} \binom{x}{r + 1} (1 - p)^{x - (r + 1)} -\frac{r p + r^2}{p^2} \\
&= r(r + 1)p^r \cdot \frac{1}{\big(1 - (1 - p)\big)^{r + 2}} -\frac{r p + r^2}{p^2} \\
&= \frac{r^2 + r}{p^2} - \frac{rp + r^2}{p^2} \\
&= \frac{r (1 - p)}{p^2}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Firstly, thankss for helping. But I derived the helper function in a different way. Can you derive $$
\frac{1}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}} = \sum_{n\geq r} \binom{n}{r}z^{n-r}, \quad \text{for }\lvert z\rvert < 1.
$$ in the way you commented?

Comment: @joshua It’s fairly straightforward to prove by induction that the $r^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $\frac{1}{1 - z}$ is $\frac{r!}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}}$, so I will leave that up to you. The $r^{\text{th}}$ derivative of the sum $\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n$ will be given by termwise differentiation (again by induction) to be $\sum_{n\geq r} n (n - 1) \cdots (n - r + 1) z^{n - r}$. Then dividing both expressions by $r!$ will give the desired equality.

Comment: thanks. You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative derivation to compute the expectation of a negative binomial distribution. Let $X_r$ be the number of trials needed to get $r$ successes, and $p$ be the probability of success on any given trial. If $r=1$, then $X_r$ has a geometric distribution, and so $\mathrm{E}(X_r)=1/p$. To prove this, let $S$ be the event that the first trial is success. By the [law of iterated expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/law-of-iterated-expectation/),
\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathrm{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathrm{P}}
\E(X_1) &= \E(X_1 \mid S)\P(S)+\E(X_1\mid S')P(S') \\[4pt]
&= (1 \cdot p)+(\E(X_1)+1)(1-p) \, ,
\end{align}
and rearranging yields the desired result. Computing $\E(X_r)$ in general is not too difficult if we use linearity of expectation. Let $A_i$ be the number of additional trials needed to get the $i$-th success once you have had $i-1$ successes. Note that $X_r=\sum_{i=1}^{r}A_i$, and so
$$
\E(X_r)=\E\left(\sum_{i=1}^r A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^r \E(A_i) \, .
$$
But the expected number of trials needed to get the $i$-th success is no different to the expected number of trials needed to get the first success, and so $\E(A_i)=\E(A_1)=\E(X_1)=1/p$. Hence, $E(X_r)=r/p$.