# Does there exist a similar identity to $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, binomial-coefficients

I know that $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

My question is does there exist a similar identity where you change the top of the choose function, o any similar to the identity above?

An example: Can you define $m$ in terms of $n$ and $k$ such that $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+m}{k}$$

Comment: No, because, for instance, $$5={5\choose 1} \neq {5+m\choose 1}=5+m$$ for any $m\neq 0$. This becomes obvious once you review the construction of pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard to define
$$
\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
$$
as, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619651/negative-binomial-coefficient). (Whether or not this needs to be a separate definition depends on how you defined the binomial coefficient in the first place, but it's pretty much always going to be the right choice.)