# Identity proof with binomial coefficients

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I have to prove the following identity and have to idea how to start.

$ { {-n} \choose k} = (-1)^k {{n+k-1} \choose k} $

I know that $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k{n \choose k}=0 $

but I cannot see a way, in which it could help prove the mentioned above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619651/negative-binomial-coefficient)

Comment: @NickyLevering partially. At the place the person in the thread writes:"the right side is clearly..."

Comment: @NickyLevering I do not really understand how he came to this transformation, would you mind explaining that?

Comment: We have: $\frac{n(n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)}{k!} = \frac{1}{k!}(n+k-1)(n+k-2) \cdots n = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!} = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can formally write $\binom {-n}{k}$ with factorial formula:
$$
\binom {-n}{k}=\frac {(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\dotsm (-n-k+1)}{k!} =\\ (-1)^{k}\frac {(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\dotsm (n)}{k!}=(-1)^{k}\binom {k+n-1}{k}
$$